# In pyspark, is df.select(column1, column2....) impact performance

Tags: performance, apache-spark, pyspark

for example, I have a dataframe with 10 columns, and later I need use this dataframe join with other dataframes. But in the dataframe only column1, and column2 are used, others are not useful.

If I do this:

```
df1 = df.select(['column1', 'column2'])
...
...
result = df1.join(other_df)....
```

Is this good for the performance?
If yes, why this is good, is there any document?

Thanks.

Comment: even you don't need to create new dataframe for same. you can use df.join(other_df.select('col2'),same,same)

Answer (score 0):

Spark is distributed lazily evaluated framework, which means either you select all columns or some of the columns they will be brought into the memory only when an action is applied to it.

So if you run

```
df.explain()
```

at any stage, it'll show you the projection of the column. So if the column is required only then it'll be available in memory else it'll not be selected.

It's better to specify the required column as it comes under best practices and also will improve your code in terms of understanding the logic.

To understand more about action and transformation visit [here](https://training.databricks.com/visualapi.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Especially for a join, the least columns you have to use (and therefore `select`), the maximum it will be efficient.

Of course, Spark is lazy & optimized, which means as long as you don't call a triggering function like `show()` or `count()` for example, it won't change anything.

So doing :

```
df = df.select(["a", "b"])
df = df.join(other_df)
df.show()
```

OR join first and select after :

```
df = df.join(other_df)
df = df.select(["a", "b"])
df.show()
```

doesn't change anything because it will optimize and choose the select first, when compiling the query with a `count()` or `show()` after.

On the other hand and to answer your question,

Doing a `show()` or `count()` in between will definitely impact performances and the one with the lowest column will be definitely faster.

Try comparing :

```
df = df.select(["a", "b"])
df.count() 
df = df.join(other_df)
df.show()
```

and

```
df = df.join(other_df)
df.count() 
df = df.select(["a", "b"])
df.show()
```

You will see the difference in time.

The difference will might not be huge, but if you're using filters (`df = df.filter("b" == "blabla")`, it can be really really big, especially if you're working with joins.

Comment: In your last comparison, you compare the time it takes to do the join once vs doing it twice, so it is expected to take more time.